# selector in jquery - get rel attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html code like this:

```
<li id="vol" rel="1">
    // something here
</li>
<li id="vol" rel="2">
    // something here
</li>
<li id="vol" rel="3">
    // something here
</li>
```

I'm try to get rel attribute by this code:

```
$('#vol').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

But it's not working. I also change `this` to `#vol`, but it didn't work.
What should i do?

Comment: can't use same id multiple times.

Comment: ...and if you fix that it will all work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Not working, I'm assuming that any `li` you click, gives you back `1`, this is caused by having multiple ID in a page. IDs are supposed to be unique, use class instead.

try

```
<li class="vol" rel="1">
    // something here
</li>
<li class="vol" rel="2">
    // something here
</li>
<li class="vol" rel="3">
    // something here
</li>

JS:

$('.vol').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).prop('rel');
});
```

Comment: By not working, I suppose only the first `li` would have a click listener bound to it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Your all `id` are same.So make different them.
Assuming that your `li` is inside `ul` which class is `clsTest`

```
$('.clsTest li').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  alert(rel);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector by "id" (#id) select only one element, use "class" (.class) instead

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
<li class="vol" rel="1">
    // something here
</li>
<li class="vol" rel="2">
    // something here
</li>
<li class="vol" rel="3">
    // something here
</li>

<script>
$('body').delegate('li.vol','click',function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `delegate` or `on` if you want to attach the event dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.li').on('click', function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('rel');
});
```

> i think we directly try with element if you have using li