# jquery selector rel=re attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, rel

I got a script from a company who handles score tables.

I would like only to show the second tab "Uitslagen" rel="re", but it standards opens on the first.
I figured that i should be possible to fake a click with JQuery.

You an see the script at : http://hvdws.nl/Uitslagen/clubplugin.html

```html
<body>
  <div id="club-plugin"></div>

  <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
  <script src="http://www.handbal.nl/kcp/e78a2135307b088e8a/"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="clubplugin2-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" href="clubplugin2-grey.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    clubplugin.load('#club-plugin'); 
   });

  </script>
 </body>
```

this is the class:

```html
<div class="o-kcp-tabs">
  <div class="o-kcp-tab-item first active" rel="pr" style="width:25%;">Programma</div>
  <div class="o-kcp-tab-item" rel="re" style="width: 25%;">Uitslagen</div>
  <div class="o-kcp-tab-item" rel="st" style="width: 25%;">Standen</div>
  <div class="o-kcp-tab-item last" rel="te" style="width: 25%;">Teams</div>
</div>
```

I found this link on Stackoverflow :
[selector in jquery - get rel attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720069/selector-in-jquery-get-rel-attribute)

But can't really figure out how exactly to write the script.

Is there someone who could help me, i feel like this is a really easy question and i'm just not skilled enough in Jquery to figure it out.

This is what i have now:

```js
$('#club-plugin').click(function(){
  var rel = $('.o-kcp-tabs').attr('rel', "re");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes all `.o-kcp-tab-item` elements that do **not** have `rel="re"` and are direct children of `.o-kcp-tabs`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.o-kcp-tabs>.o-kcp-tab-item:not([rel~="re"])').remove();
    clubplugin.load('.o-kcp-tabs'); 
});
```